# Android Gradle "Api" does not work on external library

Tags: android, api, gradle, android-library

I have an application consist of multiple modules. Those modules has external dependencies like Google Maps, Glide etc. compiled with "api" on gradle. Thus i can use that dependencies in app module too. However, I started to publish those modules on some package repository like jitpack and dependencies compiled with "api" are no longer reachable in my app module. What should I do?

App --implements-> mymodule --api-> glide (It works)

App --implements-> my module published on package repository --api-> glide (I can't reach to glide in app)

Edit: The problem was, while I'm publishing my aar on maven, it does not include other dependencies into the pom file. I have solved with updating my gradle publish with this:

```
 publications {
        "${getPublicationName()}" (MavenPublication) {
            groupId Config.groupId
            artifactId Config.artifactId
            version Config.versionName
            artifact getArtifactFilePath()

            pom.withXml {
                def dependencies = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                configurations.getByName("${getPublicationName()}CompileClasspath").getResolvedConfiguration().getFirstLevelModuleDependencies().each {
                    def dependency = dependencies.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependency.appendNode('groupId', it.moduleGroup)
                    dependency.appendNode('artifactId', it.moduleName)
                    dependency.appendNode('version', it.moduleVersion)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you find a solution?